# Datamash 1.7 outputs zero on floating point values binning

Tags: bash, floating-point, bigdata

I am using Datamash 1.7 on Centos 7.7 Linux x86_64 machine to sort and bin data which is 24 GB in size. Input data looks as follows (only first 50 samples)

```
Ind_poob
0.040618
0.006233
0.004652
0.003559
0.001752
0.001605
0.007701
0.004722
0.029899
0.00104
0.014031
6.1e-5
0.002144
0.002385
0.001145
0
0.001463
0
0.003414
0
0.001602
9.75e-4
0.007218
6.4e-5
0.006426
0
7.2e-5
1.13e-4
1.5e-4
0
4.19e-4
0.009325
7e-5
0.006592
0.01
0
0.001605
0.001924
0.003714
0.00335
0.001876
5.52e-4
0
0.019234
0.001415
1e-5
0
0.004304
2.15e-4
```

Desired Output (after scaling up)

```
#number  bin_number
4061.8  4061.8
623.3   620.00
465.2   460.00
355.9   350.00
175.2   170.00
160.5   160.00
770.1   770.00
472.2   470.00
2989.9  2980.00
104 100.00
1403.1  1400.00
6.1 0.00
214.4   210.00
238.5   230.00
114.5   110.00
0   0.00
146.3   140.00
0   0.00
341.4   340.00
0   0.00
160.2   160.00
97.5    90.00
721.8   720.00
6.4 0.00
642.6   640.00
0   0.00
7.2 0.00
11.3    10.00
15  10.00
0   0.00
41.9    40.00
932.5   930.00
7   0.00
659.2   650.00
1000    1000.00
0   0.00
160.5   160.00
192.4   190.00
371.4   370.00
335 330.00
187.6   180.00
55.2    50.00
0   0.00
1923.4  1920.00
141.5   140.00
1   0.00
0   0.00
430.4   430.00
21.5    20.00
```

but with Datamash command: `datamash -H --format=%.8f -s bin 1  <test_data.txt`, I am getting

```
bin(ind_poob)
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
```

How can I format datamash command to sort and bin input data with correct floating point format? Secondly, will it possible to plot it after binning using Gnuplot given the size of original input being 24 GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source (Since unfortunately binning isn't described very well in the documentation), numeric binning is done by this code:

```c
const long double val = num_value / op->params.bin_bucket_size;
modfl (val, & op->value);
/* signbit will take care of negative-zero as well. */
if (signbit (op->value))
  --op->value;
op->value *= op->params.bin_bucket_size;
```

Basically, it takes the integer part of dividing the number by the bucket size (where the default is 100), and multiplies that by the bucket size. So since all your numbers in your sample data are in the range `[0,1)`, every one will be in the same 0 bucket.

You might try scaling your data by multiplying it by 1e4 (Or more) to see if that'll give you better numbers (Also, no need to sort the data - you can leave off the `-s` option).

Another approach is to treat the values as strings, not numbers, and use `strbin`, which uses a different algorithm that might work better for you:

```
$ datamash -H --full strbin:100 1 < test_data.txt
Ind_poob        strbin(Ind_poob)
0.040618        60
0.006233        27
0.004652        70
0.003559        5
0.001752        30
0.001605        29
0.007701        37
0.004722        78
0.029899        25
0.00104 60
0.014031        17
6.1e-5  93
0.002144        84
0.002385        21
0.001145        57
...
```

Comment: any thoughts on plotting?

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to integrate your code with Datamash? or is to be run it independently. If so what toolchain? Could you complete the code as I don't see declaration for `op`, `params` , `header files` and how to ingest datafile? Assuming it is g++, please specify command for compiling and any specific command line switches?

Comment: @tulamba My code? I just copied that from `datamash` source. And I have no clue about plotting; not really familiar with `gnuplot`.

Comment: Thanks. How to compile this code to work with input data?

Comment: @tulamba Again, it's datamash source. So you'd build it like normal but you said you're using 1.7, which is the current release, so there's really no need to do that.

Comment: @Shawn and tulamba Thanks. Your suggestions were really useful

Comment: @user2065276 Ack, I thought tulamba was the poster, not you. Doh. Anyways, something I just thought of - you might try `strbin` instead of `bin`, see if that gives you numbers you can make use of.

Comment: @Shawn I will try and let you know tomorrow. Thanks again